# Error on running "protractor conf.js": selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\nexttick.js:41 goog.global.setTimeout(

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

On running `protractor conf.js`, browser opens up but it do not proceed any further neither browser is `maximised` or anything and it gives following error on console:

> AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\nexttick.js:41
>   goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
>                                                 ^
>       Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a
>   non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation,
>   which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.

I tried re-installing protractor and selenium-webdriver but it does not help.
I installed selenium-webdriver@2.47.0 but it also gave same error.

This project was running earlier, I did not made any changes to project and re-running this is giving above error.

I read some of the posts to make changes to `beforeEach` function and all but it do not help.

Please suggest!

Comment: It seems not to be an angular app. Did you try ignoring synchronization?
`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`

Comment: Yes, I did the same but it also did not helped